# Laravel: Pass exception to handler from try/catch block

Tags: laravel, exception

Laravel 5.7.* project. I have a customized `App\Exceptions\Handler` where I identify a number of different exceptions and do some stuff depending on environment, exception type and whatnot.

In some places i use `try/catch` blocks and in some of those situations it would be convenient to just pass the entire `\Exception $error` to the `Exceptions\Handler`.

**Q**: How do I pass it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to do something in the catch block? If you don't, just remove the try / catch. If you do, throw the exception.

```
try {

... do something ...

} catch(Exception $e) {

... do something ...

throw $e;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a laravel helper function called `report` which let's you send an exception to the Laravel error handler:

```
try {

  // your code

} catch(Exception $e) {

  report($e);

}
```